# Wordpress EduPress and businessbite Theme Installation Failed

Tags: themes

I have downloaded and installed wordpress EduPress.zip, businessbite.zip themes. Unfortunately, i found an error.

ERROR:

The package could not be installed. The theme is missing the style.css stylesheet.
Theme install failed.

Can any one help me?

Comment: Have you confirmed that there is a style.css in the zip file that couldn't be installed? That message should only pertain to one of those themes, not both.

Comment: The screencast link doesnt work. Also Edupress is being distributed as a free theme now, but you are not entitled to support. This is according to their website. Go figure. I managed to find this link on the web. Think this will help you, it did me. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/the-theme-is-missing-the-stylecss-stylesheet

Answer (score 2):

EduPress and Business Bite are both commercial themes from WPZOOM, you can just [contact their support](http://www.wpzoom.com/support/) and ask them for help. But anyway, have a look at [this screencast](http://wiki.envato.com/buying/support-buying/solving-broken-theme-issues/) which shows how to solve this issue.